# Post request from ejs view is not working

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm trying to register a user to my database but I can't even make my post request work. The get part router is working but it seems post is not working.

In the app I declared routers like this(server.js file):

```
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user.js")
app.use('/user',userRoutes)
```

In the routes/user.js file:

```
//User register
const userController = require('../controllers/user_controller')
router.get("/register",userController.register_page)
router.post("/register",userController.register_post)
```

And this is the controller part (controllers/user_controller.js):

```
    //Register get
exports.register_page = (req,res)=>{
    return res.render('user/register',{layout:false})
}
//Register post 
exports.register_post =  async (req,res)=>{
    //bla bla
    }
```

I can see the pages but when I submit in the ejs page nothing happens. This is the view page(views/user/register.ejs):

```
    <form id="register" method="post" action="/user/register">    
    <label><b>Email     
    </b>    
    </label>    
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">    
    <br><br>    
    <label><b>Password     
    </b>    
    </label>    
    <input type="Password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">    
    <br><br>
    <label><b>Confirm Password     
    </b>    
    </label>    
    <input type="Password" name="confirm" id="confirm" placeholder="Password Repeat">    
    <br><br>      
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form does not send the post request, because the submit button does not have the `type` of submit. Change from `type="button"` to `type="submit"`.

Comment: yeah that was it thank you